# SSD to USB is far faster than HDD to USB

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, usb-flash-drive

I have the following setup:

1x SSD disk
2x HDD disk in RAID 1
Win10, 8GB RAM

When I copy 1GB file from HDD to USB, the speed is `8MB/s`
The same file from HDD to SSD, the speed is `20MB/s`
The same file from SSD to USB, the speed is `40MB/s`

(measured through Windows Explorer's copy window, average results with no particular peaks, repeatable without deviations).

How is this possible?

--
**EDIT:**
I understand and don't understand the downvotes at the same time :)
I get it that SSD is faster than HDD, etc. But what makes me wonder is: apparently USB can write `40MB/s`, HDD can read `20MB/s`, so why does HDD to USB write only `8MB/s`?

Comment: "How is this possible?" - Your SSD is connected to a faster bus then your HDD, it also has the capability to write and read files faster.  *There are virtually no seek times on a SSD.*  There also is virtually no effect on fragmentation either on a SSD.

Comment: :*When I copy ... to USB"* -- USB is a bus, not a device.  That's like referring to a SSD or HDD as a "SATA".  Seems like some tests may have benefited from file caching.   Did you try a different order, i.e. use SSD as source first, and use HDD as source last?  Did you reboot between copies to ensure identical conditions?

Comment: @Ramhound - I understand that SSD is faster compared to HDD, but what makes me wonder is - apparently USB can write 40MB/s, HDD can read 20MB/s, so why does HDD to USB write only 8MB/s?

Comment: @sawdust I have tried the action in different order with the same results. I haven't tried restarting though - worth a try.

Comment: Yes, your numbers are only meaningful if measured immediately after boot (and after all other disk activities have stopped). And how much RAM do you have?

Comment: "The current answers do not contain enough detail." Like question, like answer. Your question also does not contain details: how do you measure? are the numbers average results or peaks? are they repeatable? were there any deviations observed?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - measured through Windows Explorer's copy window, these are on average with no particular peaks, repeatable without deviations.

Comment: @michalkralik You should have edited your question and added these details there; I did it for you. I'm revoking my down vote.

Comment: It´s a valid question. I´m copying USB to USB and it is really slow. Using linux 

 pv < /dev/sdb >  /dev/sdd
81.1GiB 4:59:40 [11.5MiB/s] [===================>           ] 69% ETA 2:13:20 

Will do a second copy and will copy my results from HD to USB. 
Thanks for your experiment, we will find out soon.

Comment: OK updating, copying an USB to a hard disk using DD linux 117GiB 1:28:51 [23.6MiB/s]  it took me about an hour and a half. A little more than twice as fast than copying from another USB. Now will perform copy  from the fast HD to a new 128GB generic USB. Will update after the process finish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your measurements are representative of real data transfer speeds (excluding caching and multi-tasking artifacts), one possible explanation would be that both your USB controller and RAID controller sit on the same bus (e.g. PCI-X) which they share, so they cannot perform at 100% speed at the same time.

Comment: I think this is the most probable answer

Comment: Windows does not work this way. It will first fill up the entire available RAM with data, then flush it out. 1 GB in a modern computer can likely all fit into memory. Windows is designed to work with only one bus since the days of Windows NT.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because you are copying "the same file".
Try to generate different files of the same size and try again. I am pretty sure you are experiencing caching optimization of the operating system or a controller.

It would be interesting if you experience the same behavior with different files of the same size.

You can generate random files with uncompressable content using [Dummy File Creator](http://www.mynikko.com/dummy/) to test this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your measures were probably bogus because of the way that Windows works.

There are two factors you have probably not taken into account :

1. The Windows cache : Windows has a dynamic cache that usually extends to
   at least half of the RAM, where it keeps files or programs that were read into
   memory. Files are never flushed from the cache, unless the space is required
   for new files.
   Accessing a file for the second time is very fast, since it is already
   in memory. If your computer had for example 2GB of RAM,
   then a 1GB file may fit entirely inside the RAM.
2. The Windows copy operation may be finished but not all the data is 
   necessarily flushed out to the destination media.
   The data to be written may still reside in the cache,
   and Windows will flush it out at its own time.

For a real test that gives real results, I would suggest :

1. Use a much larger file, for example with multiple copies of the 1GB file.
   Its size should be at least 3-4 times of your RAM.
2. Measure the time from when the copy started to when the disk light stopped
   blinking crazily. This is not very precise, but better than nothing.
   Or you can make the copied file much larger, so that the last part that was
   left in the cache is not significant.
3. Reboot before each test and wait for all boot actions to terminate, to always test a known and identical configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It´s a valid question. I´m copying SDD to USB, HDD to USB, USB to USB and it is slow. Using linux pv < /dev/sdb > /dev/sdd 81.1GiB 4:59:40 [11.5MiB/s] [======> ] 69% ETA 2:13:20. But copying an USB to a hard disk using DD linux 117GiB 1:28:51 [23.6MiB/s] is faster, it took me about an hour and a half. A little more than twice as fast than copying to another USB.

I also found that depends also on the bus 2.0 or 3.0 used and then brand of the USB. Cheap USB on 2.0 ports will go down to 5MiB/s, more expensive USB brand names, can go up to 10 to 12MiB/s copying USB to USB.

**Conclusion**: Depends on several factors, the PC Bus, the version of port, the brand of USBs and combination of all. Can get worse if you copy the disk image in to a HD folder and then try to copy to a USB. I think is due to de internal bus transfer. USB to USB was faster on my computer. That's my report. The best way is to got to different PCs and test, and replicate on the one that runs faster.

**ANSWER**:
Yes, its faster from SSD to USB,
its faster to copy from USB to HDD or SSD.
Really slow the other way aroud. USB writting speed is slow.

FYI: Im replicating over 100 USBs sticks for event, so I was able to replicate exact tests. AH, forgot to mention, also used WIN10 with RUFUS it only wrote up to 5.5MiB/s so there was no improvement.